# Can the TMS1802/0102, or specifically the Sinclair Executive calculator, handle an attempt to divide by zero?

Tags: sinclair, calculator

There's a sort of urban legend among people I've spoken to about Sinclair that the Executive calculator can't divide by 0. Specifically, if you do this then it goes into a busy loop, cannot be used, and drains/overheats the batteries until they run out or explode. There *is* an attested story of the [cells overheating due to the calculator being left on](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=d5m1AAAAIAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=russian), but I can't find any evidence that it would become unusable as a result of dividing by zero.

What I *can* find is that the manual for mine, which is the earlier model with the K switch (serial 19216), describes various overflow conditions and that when they occur, you clear the calculator and start again. I can't test this as I don't have the correct cells to use it.

Also [this description of the TMS1802](http://www.rskey.org/%7Emwsebastian/calcwebpg/tx_inst.htm) says that pin 13/D11 is used for overflow and error signalling, which implies that overflow detection is part of the chip. So even if it didn't have /0 protection, it would be able to signal the error and let the user clear/restart.

So is there any truth to the rumour that you could render a Sinclair Executive unusable by dividing by zero? Was there a different electronic calculator that *did* exhibit that sort of behaviour? I know that mechanical calculators can get into infinite loops when trying that.

Comment: I"m pretty sure they handled that case all right by testing the divider.

Comment: That would be a fatal flaw in the chip.

Comment: Are the correct cells unobtainable these days?

Comment: A current limited lab power supply could stand in here....

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre this was before the days when a firmware defect that made it into production could be easily mended once discovered.

Comment: @another-dave cells the same size are available, but they used to be 1.4V and are now 1.35V so don’t always work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer: [no it can't](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABFVyTtLghA). This is a later model Executive with the H/L switch (serial number 131131); apparently my manual and calculator don't match! Anyway, the calculator goes into a loop. It doesn't "break" in that it can be cleared (or switched off, or the batteries removed) but it certainly tries to calculate the answer without detecting an overflow.